# How to know whether Roaming Data is Enabled/Disabled? Programmatically

Tags: java, android, telephony, roaming

How to know whether Roaming Data is Enabled/Disabled? In the code i need to know whether Data Roaming is enabled. I can check whether phone is roaming via TelephonyManager. But how to know if Data Roaming is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
if(info.isRoaming)
{
S.O.P("data roaming");
}
```

Comment: This actually returns true even if data roaming is turned off. Further more this approach might return the WIFI NetworkInfo object if the user is connected to a WiFi network at that time.

Comment: this tells you if you are currently roaming, not if roaming is enabled.

Comment: @jaffery: yes this tells you if you are currently in Roaming. But you can use another condition for data is enabled or not. Its easy & a developer can think it itself.